# How to apply a defined class to a new class in my css?

Tags: html, css

i want to ask if is possible to apply a html class defined in css1.css to another html class who i want to defined in css2.css?

basicly

css1.css contain

```
div.classPredefined { border: solid 1px #000; }
```

and css2.css

```
div.newClass { background: #CCC; apply-class: classPredefined; }
```

I know there is no exist apply-class in css, but i want in my HTML to apply .newClass over element and automatically apply .classPrededined.

Ignore option 

`<div class="classPrededined newClass"></div>`

Thank you

Comment: When do you want to apply this? On hover? Click? On some other event?

Comment: Basically, you can't do this given that you have ruled out the only viable option.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I assume that you cannot manually alter the html and you want to add a specific class on a click event.I dont think there is a css method to add class to an existing element,but you can it is achieve using jQuery.

```
$(".newClass").addClass("classPredefined");
```

This simply add a predefined class to an element with the class newClass.

If you simply want two elements with different classes to have the same css style, I suppose you could create a new class with the common properties and add this class to necessary elements.

Comment: sorry ... javascript jQuery is not an option

Comment: I am not sure what you are trying to do. Is this a hover state? Or is there a specific instance where you want this class to appear?

Comment: [code]<div class="menu2 pull-right ui-corner-all span3 img-polaroid boxError"></div>[/code]

Answer (score 1):

So do you want the new style to always apply? If so, you can use the exact same class name in the file loaded after the first one and the latter style will be added to the first one. So if you have

```
div.classPredefined { border: solid 1px #000; }
```

In the css1.css, you can use the same class in css2.css

```
div.classPredefined { background: #CCC; }
```

The file will adapt both of the styles.

You could try to explain what you want on this..

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use.

```
div.newClass { 
    @import url("css1.css");
    background: #CCC; 
    //border: solid 1px #000; //css from the older class
}
```

You Can easily add css file within another css file just doing `@import("");`

Comment: because css1.css contain declarations of bootstrap. In fact i dont want to reinvented the cicle. I want to update the invented circle.

Comment: Then use @import url("css1.css"); on your css2.css